# Interpreting results of mvnorm.etest using energy package in R

Tags: normal-distribution, data-visualization, multivariate-normal-distribution, ggplot2, univariate

I need to use functionalities of the `energy package` installed in R to give energy test of normality. So, as given in its documentation here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/energy/energy.pdf, I use the `mvnorm.etest`, `mvnorm.e` and normal.e to get univariate and multivariate normality tests respectively.

For the multivariate normality, I write this code

```
> mvnorm.etest(DATAFINALE[1:1667,1:28], R)

    Energy test of multivariate normality: estimated parameters

data:  x, sample size 1667, dimension 28, replicates 5
E-statistic = -2.9787e+84, p-value = 1
```

And for the univariate normality, I have

```
   > normal.e(DATAFINALE[1:1667,27])

[1] 281.8001
```

My question is composed of two parts:

1. How do I interpret these results to test the univariate and
   multivariate normality?
2. How plot results of the test to make it more visible?

You can use the iris dataset to reproduce results.
Thank you for your suggestions!